# How to compare 4 columns with 2 conditions in Excel

Tags: excel, function, if-statement, excel-formula, countif

I have 4 columns in Excel A, B, C, D. Where data in A have their B's dates, and data in C have their D's dates

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aa | 10.09.2023 3:52:30 | dd | 26.09.2023 12:52:19 |
| 2 | bb | 13.09.2023 4:15:22 | aa | 10.09.2023 3:50:31 |
| 3 | cc | 19.09.2023 16:03:07 | ee | 19.09.2023 16:03:07 |
| 4 | aa | 10.09.2023 3:45:10 | cc | 18.09.2023 14:36:12 |

I need common data from columns A and C, with the condition that the date in column B is greater than the date in D.

I tried the function `=IF(AND(COUNTIF(C:C,A1); B1>D:D); 1; 0)` 
Then I selected all 1 through the filter, everything seemed to work out, but in some cases it considers some lines as true, even if date B is less than date D.

Please tell me why this function does not calculate accurately, and what formula can be used to get the desired result?

My expected result

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aa | 10.09.2023 3:52:30 | dd | 26.09.2023 12:52:19 | 1 |
| 2 | bb | 13.09.2023 4:15:22 | aa | 10.09.2023 3:50:31 | 0 |
| 3 | cc | 19.09.2023 16:03:07 | ee | 19.09.2023 16:03:07 | 1 |
| 4 | aa | 10.09.2023 3:45:10 | cc | 18.09.2023 14:36:12 | 0 |

Comment: What is the expected result (e.g. `aa, bb, cc`) and where (e.g. `E1` or `E1:E3`)? Maybe replace the data with more relevant data and share a screenshot of the result(s).

Comment: i add my expected result to the post, i want to et my result like bool data (1 or 0) in E1:E4

Comment: If don't get the expected results to be honest since there is no 'ee' in column A. Yet your results show that they have a value in common.

Comment: @JvdV this 1 is not for ee, it is for A3 and B3

Comment: @VBasic2008 sorry it is not working(

Comment: Try `=IFERROR(N(B1>INDEX(D$1:D$4,MATCH(A1,C$1:C$4,0))),)` and copy down or `=IFERROR(N(B1:B4>XLOOKUP(A1:A4,C1:C4,D1:D4)),)` to spill down. It is assumed that the values in columns `B` and `D` are dates, not text as their left alignment would imply. In the latter case, investigate the `DATEVALUE` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original formula was kind of close but because you are using 2 criteria, use COUNTIFS instead of just COUNTIF:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($C$1:$C$4;A1;$D$1:$D$4;"<"&B1)>0;1;0)
```

[COUNTIFS Function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842)

This function, as described in the documentation, allows user to input multiple criteria, and each criteria is range based. Your formula got 2 criterias: column A and column B.

First part of formula is like this:

`COUNTIFS($C$1:$C$4;A1`

This part will just count how many cells in range C1:C4 are equal to the value of A1. Next part is like this:

`$D$1:$D$4;"<"&B1`

This will count how many cells in range D1:D4 got a **lower** value than the value showed at B1 (your date).

Because we are using COUNTIFS all critera used will be checked as an AND condition. That means that **all of them** must be fulfilled or the count will be zero. So all together like this is:

```
COUNTIFS($C$1:$C$4;A1;$D$1:$D$4;"<"&B1)
```

This means *count how many **rows** in range C1:D4 meet these requirements **at the same time***:

1. Range C1:C4 must contain the value in A1 (and so on because of relative references)
2. Range D1:D4 must have a date lower than date at B1.

Then I combined all this with an IF because you don't want the total count, you just want to know if there is at least one that meet your requirementes. That explains the `>0` part. It is something like this:

`IF (previouscount > 0 then return 1, else return 0)`

Comment: OMG, this helps me thank yo very much! but i but I don’t understand, can you explain the formula to me? for example why "<"&B1 or >0?

Comment: @NigarHesenli check updated answer and I strongly encourage you to read the documentation about COUNTIFS

Comment: it turns out to be so easy, thank you very much! i have last question,  can this formula be used without `>0` ?

Comment: @NigarHesenli I guess you mean to delete the IF part and use the COUNTIFS part. Sure, try it! It's the best way to learn how it works!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the clarifications in the comment-section. My two cents:

[image]

Formula in `F1`:

```
=--IFNA(B1:B4>VLOOKUP(A1:A4,C1:D4,2,0),)
```

The `VLOOKUP()` will return an error when `A1:A4` can't be found, this would then be turned into a 0 through `IFNA()`'s 2nd parameter.